# EntiryFramework in WebApp: HowTo Store DSN

Tags: asp.net, security, entity-framework

i'm using the entity framework in a asp.net 3.5 web application.

What is best practice to store the database connection string in a
secure (encrypted) way? (i'm using username/password to get to the database)

(i have to delete the model very often, as the database designer in vs2008
does not update the foreign keys very good).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to encrypt the configuration section in your web.config file that holds the connection string.  See [this support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/329290) for more information.

Comment: Hi, but this does not solve the problem im the development cycle, and does not help me while developing the app. Do you use this behavior in your development process?

Comment: In our situation, it is not very important to encrypt the connection string while developing it in-house.  It becomes important when we deploy.  Therefore, we leave it unencrypted until we deploy it.